# Добавление юзеров и выборка каждого из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Есть две страницы:**

1) на одной странице идёт только добавление пользователей, паролей, где они сидят (на каком ПК) и т.д

*сама таблица*

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `login` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `familiya` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `imya` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `otchestvo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `room` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `division` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass_pc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pass_favalert` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

*код добавления в БД*

```
<?php require_once("shapka.php");?>
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connect.php');

  //Функция добавления данных в БД
  function getInsert($login,$familiya,$imya,$otchestvo,$room,$division,$pass_pc,$pass_favalert,$birthday){

    //Создаем запрос к БД
    $time=time();
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (login,familiya,imya,otchestvo,room,division,pass_pc,pass_favalert,birthday) VALUES('$login','$familiya','$imya','$otchestvo','$room','$division','$pass_pc','$pass_favalert','$birthday')");

     if(!$insert){
        return exit('Ошибка добавления данных в БД');
     }
     //Если данные добавились успешно
     echo "<div class='hero-unit' style='margin:15px 30px;'><center><h3>Пользователь успешно добавлен.";
     echo "</u></h3><br />Добавить нового пользователя можно <a href='index.php?page=добавление пользователей'>здесь</a></center></div>";

  }
  //Вызываем функцию только после нажатия на кнопке
  if($_POST['button']){
  //Вызов функции getInsert()
   getInsert($_POST['login'],$_POST['familiya'],$_POST['imya'],$_POST['otchestvo'],$_POST['room'],$_POST['division'],$_POST['pass_pc'],$_POST['pass_favalert'],$_POST['birthday']);
   }
?>
```

2) А есть страница добавления оборудования, если мы добавляем ПК, то есть графа "пользователи", мы должны указать юзеров, которые сидят на этом ПК, надо сделать так, что бы по мере вписывания логина, выдавался список (как в гугле по мере заполнения) если есть данный логин в БД. а если нету, то нету, и надо добавить.

*дамп таблицы*

```
CREATE TABLE `devices` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name_device` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `netname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '000.000.0.000',
  `room` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не установлено',
  `division` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cp` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  `motherboard` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  `ram` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  `hdd` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  `vga` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  `dvd` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  `corpus` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  `users` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  `serial_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  `invent_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Не имеет',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;
```

*код*

```
<?php require_once("shapka.php");?>
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connect.php');

//Функция добавления данных в БД
    function getInsert($name_device,$netname,$ip,$room,$division,$cp,$motherboard,$ram,$hdd,$vga,$dvd,$corpus,$serial_number,$invent_number,$users){

//Создаем запрос к БД
    $time=time();
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO devices (name_device,netname,ip,room,division,cp,motherboard,ram,hdd,vga,dvd,corpus,serial_number,invent_number,users) VALUES('$name_device','$netname','$ip','$room','$division','$cp','$motherboard','$ram','$hdd','$vga','$dvd','$corpus','$serial_number','$invent_number','$users')");

    if(!$insert){
        return exit('Ошибка добавления данных в БД');
    }
 //Если данные добавились успешно
    echo "<div class='hero-unit' style='margin:15px 30px;'><center><h3>Техника успешно добавлена.";
    echo "</u></h3><br />Добавить новую технику можно <a href='index.php?page=добавление техники'>здесь</a></center></div>";

}
//Вызываем функцию только после нажатия на кнопке
    if($_POST['button']){
//Вызов функции getInsert()
/*var_dump($_POST);*/
        getInsert($_POST['name_device'],$_POST['netname'],$_POST['ip'],$_POST['room'],$_POST['division'],$_POST['cp'],$_POST['motherboard'],$_POST['ram'],$_POST['hdd'],$_POST['vga'],$_POST['dvd'],$_POST['corpus'],$_POST['serial_number'],$_POST['invent_number'],$_POST['users']);
    }

   //Закрываем соединение
   @mysql_close($insert);
?>
```

P.S Как только мы добавили оборудование, в списке (таблице всего оборудования, надо сделать ссылки на логинах, то есть нажимаешь на логин, открывается страница этого юзера со всей информацией.)

И ещё: вводить логины надо через запятую, что бы каждый просматривался в БД (как на этом сайте, когда выбираешь теги темы)

Как так сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы о авто заполнении, то [вот хороший урок](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1336)

Вот ещё [хорошая статья](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)